# NullPointerException while using a setter injection of SessionFactory bean

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, struts2

I am getting null pointer exception. The setter injection is not working I guess. I tried to look into server logs but not being able to find the root cause.

**`applicationContext.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">
 
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
        
        <!-- Database Configuration -->
        
    <import resource="DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>
 
    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="UsersBean.xml"/>
        
</beans>
```

**`DataSource.xml`:**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
 
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test;create=true" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="deflection" />
  </bean>
 
</beans>
```

**`UsersBean.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">    
        
        
        <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="mainAction" class="com.riteshsangwan.integration.MainAction">
            
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**`ModelClass`:**

```
package com.riteshsangwan.integration;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ModelClass implements Serializable {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long mid;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public long getMid() {
        return mid;
    }

    public void setMid(long mid) {
        this.mid = mid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    
}
```

**`MainAction.java`:**

```
package com.riteshsangwan.integration;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class MainAction extends ActionSupport
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String execute(){
        ModelClass m=new ModelClass();
        m.setName("Ritesh");
        m.setEmail("sangwan.ritesh@yahoo.in");
        Session s=sessionFactory.openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(m);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**`HibernateSessionFactory.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
 
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
 
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.riteshsangwan.integration" />
 
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
         
       </props>
    </property>
 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**`pom.xml`:**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="main" class="com.riteshsangwan.integration.MainAction">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: At which line do you get the NPE?

Comment: @K.C. Session s=sessionFactory.opensession(); I debug the application and find out that sessionFactory is null. Please help me to resolve this I have been trying to integrate spring with hibernate from a week and still not done

Comment: post your HibernateSessionFactory.xml please :)

Comment: @K.C. check the edits forget to post it at time of asking question

Comment: Show us where you use `MainAction` bean.

Comment: What is your `struts.xml`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis MainAction is a strutsaction class. the execute method gets invoked. I didn't know how to use mainAction bean or what you mean by using mainAction bean. pls correct me If I am wrong anywhere

Comment: @RomanC pasted the struts.xml 
please help me buddy stuck in spring + hibernate integration for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your `Action`'s bean managed by Spring try

```xml
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
```

which is used by default in `struts-plugin.xml` of the [Spring plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/spring).

in the action config use bean id as a value for `class` attribute

```xml
<action name="main" class="mainAction">
```

As far as you are using Spring annotations include in the spring config

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.riteshsangwan.integration"/>
```

also make sure the Struts [Spring plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/spring) is deployed. Add the following dependency to `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Detailed explanation with examples you could find [Spring and Struts 2](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/spring.html).

The version of xsd schema is not the same as in pom.xml, you should update spring config to the version you use.

```xml
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
```

is available for Spring 3.2.

Comment: It solves the problem of sessionFactory being null. But now when I try to run the application it seems that the tables are not created by hibernate on startup. What could be the possible reasons for tables not get created. I check the complete code and even debugged it line by line. Everything is fine.

Comment: Did you create a schema and user, did you give rights to user create tables in the schema? Are you using `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>`?

Comment: thanks buddy you are a life saver a silly mistake
not setting hbm2ddl property. I have been following this tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/
In this tutorial hbm2ddl is missing

Comment: Another option to create schema is to use URL `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`.